# Deleting an allocated array of strings

Tags: c

I've a function that returns a list of dynamically allocated arrays that can be looped upon.  The caller is freeing the list but still getting leak warnings from valgrind.

I'm using this version so the caller doesn't need to know the length of the array and it can simply loop upon until NULL.

```
char **getList() {
    char **list = (char *[]){"John Doe", "Jane Doe", NULL};
    char **values = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1);
    int i = 0;
    while(*list) {
        values[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(*list) + 1));
        strcpy(interests[i++], *list);
        list++;
    }
    values[i] = NULL;
    return values;
}
```

Caller level

```
int main() {
    char **values = getList();
    while(*values) {
        // do something with the *value
        values++;
    }
    free(values); // free up the values

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You allocate one pointer for `values`; you try to put two values into it; the memory system is not going to be happy with you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually three values including `NULL` are put there.

Comment: @MikeCAT — Hmm; yes.  The `while (*list)` ensures that the loop doesn't execute on the null pointer, but the `values[i] = NULL;` after the loop adds the extra value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `values` is incremented, so `free(values);` after that is invalid.
- The strings pointed at by elements of `values` is not freed.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    char **value_list = getList(), **values;
    values = value_list;
    while(*values) {
        // do something with the *value
        values++;
    }
    // free up the values
    for (values = value_list; *values; values++) {
        free(*values);
    }
    free(value_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that

```
    char **values = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1);
```

in the function `getList()` should be

```
    char **values = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
```

to avoid out-of-bounds writes.

Comment: is this line ok? `values[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(*list) + 1));` in context of +1? Or it should be `sizeof(char) * strlen(*list) + 1`

Comment: `sizeof(char) * (strlen(*list) + 1)` is good because it means "allocating (the length of string + 1 (for terminating null-character)) `char`s". `sizeof(char) * strlen(*list) + 1` is OK because `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 and the two values will be same, but not good because it is less meaningfull. `values[i] = malloc(strlen(*list) + 1);` is also good to avoid redundancy.